# Bypass hibernate on boot on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, hibernate

I have a problem where Ubuntu is shutting down immediately after restarting from Hibernate. I want to boot without Hibernating. Can I use grub options/commands to set it to ignore the Hibernate image for the next boot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The kernel will ignore the resume partition used to restart from hibernate if you pass it the '**noresume**' option at boot. Pass this as a kernel option at the grub bootloader. See [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re33.html) and [here](http://www.tuxonice.net/FAQ-5.html#ss5.3).

For a more permanent solution, [you can append this option to your default boot image](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=422875) so it never looks to resume from a hibernate image.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't use grub (like on my PowerBook G4), you can pass arguments without grub. On my PowerBook, you do it by typing `Linux noresume` on the yaboot command line. On devices with u-boot (like a Mips Creator CI20 and many other single board computers, maybe even a raspberry pi), you need to connect a TTL serial cable to the correct pins on the board and access the boot console over the serial link (either with an RS232 terminal and voltage shifter or a terminal emulator on another computer.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the noresume option. I'm not sure if I actually used it correctly but the boot behaviour was different. This allowed me to do an CTRL-ALT-F2, get a terminal, login and shutdown.

A colourful menu appeared and I selected boot. I booted and then restarted again from login screen.

All seems OK now.